# Behat with mink clean before each test

Tags: testing, behat, mink

I am trying to find a way to run cleanup (DB) before running on each test. How could I do if I am using behat with mink? My current FeatureContext.php looks like this:

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     * Every scenario gets its own context object.
     *
     * @param array $parameters context parameters (set them up through behat.yml)
     */
    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        // Initialize your context here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the hooks in your context, read [docs for Behat 3](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/3.hooks.html) or [Behat 2](http://docs.behat.org/guides/3.hooks.html). Example from Behat 3:

```
// features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Testwork\Hook\Scope\BeforeSuiteScope;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterScenarioScope;

class FeatureContext implements Context
{
    /**
     * @BeforeSuite
     */
     public static function prepare(BeforeSuiteScope $scope)
     {
         // prepare system for test suite
         // before it runs
     }

     /**
      * @AfterScenario @database
      */
     public function cleanDB(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
     {
         // clean database after scenarios,
         // tagged with @database
     }
}
```